# how to find the value of alpha and beta

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

here is a question :

> if $a$ and $b$ are the zero of polynomial $ f(x)=2x^2-9x+9$, then $1/a+1/b$ is equal to :
>
> (a) $9/2$     (b)  $3/9$      (c)  $1$   (d) $-1$

which is the correct answer?

well actually $a $ and $b$ are alpha and beta here.

i solve upto here :

$a+b = 9/2$, and $ab = 9/2$

because alpha + beta = -b/a and alpha*beta = c/a. i tried to reciprocal a+b but that will come to 2/9 but here  the answer is 1 !

and after that i got confused.....(answer is: c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $ab=\frac92$ and $a+b=-\frac{-9}{2}=\frac92$. In fact given a 2-degree polynomial $Ax^2+Bx+C$, the sum of the roots is $-\frac{B}{A}$, while their product is $\frac{C}{A}$.
So$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{a+b}{ab}=\frac{\frac92}{\frac92}=1$$

Comment: you're welcome! ;)

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac 1a + \frac 1b = \frac {a+b}{ab}$$

That's simply expressing $\frac 1a + \frac 1b$ as one fraction after finding the common denominator.

That gives you the value $\dfrac{\frac 92}{\frac 92} = 1$, as desired.

Comment: thanks   @amWhy for your answer

Comment: You're welcome, anni!

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1a+\frac1b=\frac1a\cdot\frac bb+\frac1b\cdot\frac aa=\frac{b+a}{ab}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You're welcome @anni. :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively: $\frac1a$ and $\frac1b$ are the roots of the polynomial $X^2f(\frac1X) = 9X^2-9X+2$, so they sum to $1$.

Comment: well thanks for that....

Comment: No problem, you had the same answer thrice already so I thought I'd add a different one for some variety...